# Can I use a Wii Guitar Hero Guitar on PC?

Tags: pc, guitar-hero-world-tour, guitar-hero-3, guitar-hero-aerosmith

For Guitar Hero 3: Legends of Rock, Guitar Hero: Aerosmith and Guitar Hero: World Tour, can I use a wireless Wii Guitar Hero 3: Legends of Rock controller on PC with a Bluetooth Dongle? My controllers work perfectly with the Bluetooth Dongle on PC, but will it work with the peripheral and will the game recognize it as a controller?

Comment: You should give it a shot first, I guess...

Comment: @Wingzero I haven't bought the games yet because I want to know if I will also have to buy a different guitar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does seem possible with bluetooth and some additional pieces of software.

Here's a link for some setup instructions:

http://www.mundayweb.com/html/Using%20the%20Wii%20Guitar%20Hero%20III%20with%20a%20PC.html

As pointed out in the comments, the guide is a little dated, but here is a video of the glovePIE program working on Windows 7:

Comment: Nice guide! (If the OP was using Windows XP)

Comment: @LoboDemon I'll buy the game soon to see if it works. Thanks!